# Button click event not firing in case of update panel, AsyncPostBackTrigger also defined

Tags: asp.net, button, updatepanel

I am fetching data from DB and assign it to repeater.

When I click on button event it only goes to page load function but not to the required on-click event.
I am confused as to why this is happening.

And when I comment out repeater its working fine. I don't why it's not working with repeater in page load.

**Aspx code:**

```
<form runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"  pdateMode="Conditional"  ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Next Availabilities" 
        OnClick="Button2_Click" />

    <asp:Repeater id="repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""><%# Eval("Time") %></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="Button3" EventName ="Click" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="Button2" EventName ="Click" />
    </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your UpdatePanel:

- Correct `pdateMode` to `UpdateMode`
- Remove `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`
- Add starting tag of `<ContentTemplate>`
- Assign id `ID="UpdatePanel1"`

  ```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
  ```